# Bash prompts for replacing strings and variables in files?

Tags: bash

So I'm looking how I can put together a Bash script that can give prompts to a use for mass changing strings and variables in files in files and apply changes to all files that have that string or variable to a new one.

Case in point for example I had a bunch of files that have a string with a number value in it, and I want to change it to a new value, ie;

```
font-size=30
```

and let's say I want to change 30 to a different number value of 25. I know this can be achievable by doing;

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/font-size=30/font-size=25/g' {} \;
```

but if I wanted it to be intractable to let the user change to any value by typing it in themselves in the bash prompt, like so, ie;

```
Search and replace all font values of %n
Font size Value = 30
Enter new value:
```

How would I be able to do this as an intractable prompt that asks for a user's input? So not only just being able to search and replace all instances of values belonging to `Font-size=` but searching and replacing other values such as `x` and `y` position values also.

All I'm basically looking to do is making a prompt menu where you have to select from the menu what you want to do, and then do as  I've described above. Give it an input file, or a directory containing a bunch of files, take the following for example;

```
Choose from menu [1-3]:

1 - Replace Font-size values
2 - Replace X and Y values
3 - Exit

- - -
Select file or directory target: <user_input_here>
```

Comment: Do you mean interactive instead of intractable (_not easily governed, managed, or directed_ according to Merriam-Webster dict.)?

Comment: interactive, intractable, what's the difference really?

Comment: They are two completely different terms with radically different meanings. The only relation I can think of is that they are both English words.

Comment: What is the format of the file?

Comment: @ReutSharabani - The file formats are `*.layout` and `*.styles`

Comment: If all the files are in the same directory (or no more than 2 deep) then using `sed` directly with file globbing is much more efficient than using `find` to spawn a separate instance of `sed` once per-file, e.g. `sed -i 's/font-size=30/font-size=25/g' *.{layout,styles}`

Comment: Take a look at the `select` keyword in bash, it can prompt a list of choices and ask the user for input

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `read` to create an interactive `bash` script. See the corresponding [manpage](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html) for more information on this utility.

Look at the following example which you can easily extend to your needs:

```
#!/bin/bash

function replace_fontsize {
  read -p "Old font-size: (Press Enter) " old_size
  read -p "New font-size: (Press Enter) " new_size
  read -p "Select file or directory target: (Press Enter) " path
  if [ -d "$path" ] ; then
    find "$path" -type f -exec sed -i 's/font-size=${old_size}/font-size=${new_size}/g' {} \;
  elif [ -f "$path" ] ; then
    sed -i 's/font-size=${old_size}/font-size=${new_size}/g' "$path"
  else
    echo "File/Directory ${path} doesn't exist"
    exit 1
  fi
}

function replace_x_and_y {
  # do whatever you want
  exit 0
}

echo "Choose from menu [1-3]:

1 - Replace Font-size values
2 - Replace X and Y values
3 - Exit"

read -n 1 -s menu

case $menu in
  1) replace_fontsize;;
  2) replace_x_and_y;;
  3) exit 0;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# put any X here for X in the format X=<number>
options=("font-size" "x")

echo "Choose from menu [1-$((${#options[@]}+1))]"
index=1
for i in ${options[@]}; do
    echo -e "\t$((index++)) - $i"
done
echo -e "\t$((index)) - exit"

read -p 'select: ' sel                                                                                                                                
if ! [[ $sel =~ [1-9][0-9]* ]]; then
    echo "invalid selection. enter a number greater than 0"
    exit 1
fi
if [[ $sel -eq $index ]]; then
    echo "exiting.."
    exit 0
fi
echo "updating '${options[$((--sel))]}'"
read -p "enter the old value: " oval
read -p "enter the new value: " nval
echo "updating '${options[$sel]}=$oval' into '${options[$sel]}=$nval'"

# change the directory here if required and update the find query as needed
find . -type f -exec sed -i "s:${options[$sel]}=$oval:${options[$sel]}=$nval:g" {} \;
```